# Help to set up RTSP Stream Server in C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, streaming, rtsp

I am not a socket programmer, but I need to develop a RTSP streaming server in c# .net.
I am developing a blackberry application, but it does not have native video calling support. So to fulfill my requirement, I want to create an intermediate streaming server, that will capture my video data (live bytes) from one BB device, and send it to another BB device. This will be live streaming, just like video calling.
But I have no idea on how to implement it in c# .net. I have tried to google for some code, but didn't get any useful links. 
Please suggest if I am not on the right track. I am asking for c# .net as I feel it a bit easier to build for someone newbie like me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out https://net7mma.codeplex.com/
It has a RtspServer and RtspClient and a bunch of other goodies. It works with VLC out of the box.



Check out the CodeProject Article @ http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507218/Managed-Media-Aggregation-using-Rtsp-and-Rtp

Answer (score 2):

RTSP is going to be a very difficult choice for this. It requires coordinating a TCP control socket and multiple separate channels of UDP data.

You're much better off with any variant of HTTP Video or RTMP or RTMPF. HTTP Video has no single standard--just break up video and send in chunks. Easy. RTMP is used with Flash but can be used separately. There arr sample apps in .NET and Java. RTMPF is also used by Flash but is UDP based instead of TCP and is Peer-to-Peer focused. I think there are also sample implementations available.

Sam

Comment: Thanks Samuel for your help. Can u please post any links or sample implementations if you have any?

Comment: Sample implementation @ https://net7mma.codeplex.com/